# PHP, запись в JSON

Tags: php, json

Пытаюсь записать в JSON с помощью php.Первый раз записывается и можно использовать файл, а второй раз возвращает null при декодировании из-за неправильного формата json файла, вот код который пишет

```
$name = clean($_POST['title']);
$message = clean($_POST['message']);

$new_post = array("title" => $name, "text" => $message);
$new_post = json_encode($new_post);

file_put_contents('data.json', $new_post, FILE_APPEND);

echo "Success";

function clean($value = ""){
     $value = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripcslashes(trim($value))));
     return $value;
}
```

А пишет в таком виде
    {"title":"value1", "text":"value2"}{"title":"value3", "text":"value4"}....
Пишет в одну строку, не переносит каретку ниже.Из-за этого после второй записи в этот файл его невозможно использовать
Вот код который читает:

```
<?php
$title = clean($_GET['query']);

function clean($value = ""){
    $value = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripcslashes(trim($value))));
    return $value;
}

$result_string = search($title);

function search($title = ""){
$ret_str = "";
$text = file_get_contents('../data.json');
$obj = json_decode($text, true);
echo in_array($title, $obj);
foreach ($obj as $key=>$value){
    if($title == $value){
        $ret_str = $obj['text'];
    }else{
        echo "WTF?!";
    }
 }
 return $ret_str;
 }

 echo "<br>".$result_string;
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON не предназначен для дозаписи значений.

Перевод строки можно сделать воспользовавшись штатной константой `PHP_EOL`

```
file_put_contents('data.json', $new_post.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Вот только не поможет. Две записи должны выглядеть вот так:

```
[
{"title":"value1", "text":"value2"},
{"title":"value3", "text":"value4"}
]
```

Хотя в простом случае можете

1. файл создавать изначально с открытой скобкой `[` и первой записью данных
2. дозаписывать `','.PHP_EOL.$new_json_row`
3. при чтении файла, но перед декодированием json добавлять в конец `]` и только потом декодировать.

Но выглядит как костыль.

Не зная исходную задачу дальше сложно что-то сказать. Но скорей всего вам уместнее взять нормальную СУБД.

Comment: Вы правы, тут просто нужно снести и поставить новую ОС(win7).Я проверю чуть позже и если поможет то поставлю +