# Как вставить PHP-код в JSON?

Tags: php, json, ios, swift

Задача вывести данные из БД на айфоне. Вопрос - Можно ли как-то интегрировать php в данный json?

```
[

{"name":"Песто кафе", "price":"350 р"},
{"name":"Пропаганда", "price":"350 р"},
{"name":"Кофемания", "price":"710 р"}

]
```

такой вариант не работает:

```
{"name":"<?=$row['rest_name'];?>", "price":"<?=$row['price'];?>"},
```

Comment: а как вы собираетесь на айфоне запускать php-код? О_о

Comment: Похожий: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747340/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-php-%d0%b2-json и этот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528542/php-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-json

Comment: Эдуард, на айфоне не php, а значение.

Comment: уточню вопрос, есть ios приложение, которое обращается к API. Я создал файл api.php, его код сверху. Но я хочу забирать данные из БД, поэтому пробую подставить значение посредством PHP в этом же файле. Возможно я не правильно сформулировал изначальный вопрос. Сам не могу разобраться...

Comment: Дайте Ваш код на формирование  json

Comment: Razik у меня пока нет другого кода. Попробую поработать с тем, что вы прислали.

Comment: немного подправил и помогло, спасибо @RaZik!

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вопрос

```
// $rows - данные из БД
$rows = [
    0 => [
        'rest_name'=>'Песто кафе',
        'price'=>'350 р'
        ],
    1 => [
        'rest_name'=>'Пропаганда',
        'price'=>'350 р'
        ],
    2 => [
        'rest_name'=>'Кофемания',
        'price'=>'710 р'
        ],
    ];
$json = [];
foreach ($rows as $row){
    $json[] = [
        'name'  => $row['rest_name'],
        'price' => $row['price']
    ];
}

$json = json_encode($json);
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: Или используя стиль ФП `$json = json_encode(array_map(function($row){ return ['name' => $row['rest_name'], 'price' => $row['price']];}, $rows));` , где $rows - ряды из базы

Answer (score 0):

если исполняемый js-скрипт находится не на стороне сервера, а например в файле .js то php не будет ему виден. Сначала необходимо получить php данные в данный js-скрипт, например:  `<input type="hidden" name="get-remote-addr" id="get-remote-addr" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" />`
далее:

```
var ip = $('input[name=get-remote-addr]').val();
{ "ip" : ip };
```